# How to get only values from one collection if their foreign key exists in other table

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, data-binding

I have two tables in my db. One artists containing id and artistname, a second table albums containing a foreign key artistid. 
I have cascaded two comboboxes together so that per artist only their albums show. This works. I have a trackviewmodel to add tracks. But I have an artistname in my first table that doesn't have an album yet, and when I select that artist from the combobox, I get a null exception (object not set). How can I populate the first combobox artists only when in the second table that artistid exists. 
In my view I bind to the collection Artists, so it makes sense it retrieves all the values in the collection, but I only want those where the artistid exist in the albums collection.

Sorry for the long post, this is the first time I ask a question here, but I'm really stuck. Thanks in advance for help

this is for c#, mvvm pattern, entity framework. 
I've already tried this but can't figure out how to hook this up to the first combobox:

```
public ICollection<Album> AlbumWithArtist()    
        {     
        return context.Albums.Where(p => p.ArtistId >= 1 && p.ArtistId.HasValue).ToArray();     
        }     

//Dataclasses    
public class Artist    
    {    
        public int Id { get; set; }    
        public string ArtistName { get; set; }     
        public ICollection<Album> Albums { get; set; }    
    }     
public class Album    
    {    

        public int Id { get; set; }    
        public Artist Artist { get; set; }    
        public virtual int? ArtistId { get; set; }    
        public string AlbumName { get; set; }    
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }     
        public virtual int? GenreId { get; set; }     
        public int NumberOfTracks { get; set; }    
    }

//TrackViewModel    
    public class TrackViewModel : ViewModel    
    {     
        private List<Artist> _artists;      
        private Artist _selectedArtist = new Artist();     
        private Album _selectedAlbum = new Album();     
        private readonly BusinessContext context;     
        private ICollection<Track> _tracks;     
        private int _trackNumber;     
        private string _trackName;

        public TrackViewModel() : this(new BusinessContext())
        {

        }

        public TrackViewModel(BusinessContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.Artists = new List<Artist>();
            this.Albums = new CustomObservableCollection<Album>();
            Tracks = new ObservableCollection<Track>();
            GetArtistList();
            GetAlbumByArtist();

        }

        private bool _uploaded = false;

        public bool Uploaded
        {
            get { return _uploaded; }
            set { _uploaded = value; }
        }

        public ICollection<Track> Tracks
        {
            get { return _tracks; }
            set { _tracks = value; }
        }

        public List <Artist> Artists
        {
            get
            {
                return _artists;
            }

            set
            {
                _artists = value;

            }
        }

        public Artist SelectedArtist
        {
            get
            {
            return _selectedArtist; 
            }
            set
            {
                _selectedArtist = value;
                this.Albums.Repopulate(_selectedArtist.Albums);
            }
        }

        public Album SelectedAlbum
        {
            get
            {
                    return _selectedAlbum;
            }
            set
            {
                _selectedAlbum = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedArtist");
            }
        }

        public int TrackNumber
        {
            get { return _trackNumber; }
            set { _trackNumber = value; }
        }

        public string TrackName
        {
            get { return _trackName; }
            set { _trackName = value; }
        }

        public ActionCommand AddTrackCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new ActionCommand(p => AddTrack());

            }
        }

        private void AddTrack()
        {
            using (var api = new BusinessContext())

            {
                var track = new Track
                {

                    ArtistId = SelectedArtist.Id,
                    AlbumId = SelectedAlbum.Id,
                    TrackNumber = TrackNumber,
                    TrackName = TrackName,
                    Uploaded = Uploaded
                };
                try
                {
                    api.AddTrack(track);
                }
                catch (NotSupportedException)
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException();

                }

                Tracks.Add(track);
            }
        }

        private void GetArtistList()
        {
            Artists.Clear();
            foreach (var ar in context.GetArtistList())
                Artists.Add(ar);
        }

        private void GetAlbumList()
        {
            Albums.Clear();
            foreach (var al in context.GetAlbumList())
                Albums.Add(al);
        }

        private void GetAlbumByArtist()
        {
            Albums.Clear();

            foreach (var al in context.AlbumWithArtist())
                Albums.Add(al);
        }

    }
//Class CustomObservableCollection<T>    

    public class CustomObservableCollection <T>: ObservableCollection <T>
    {
        public CustomObservableCollection() : base()
        {

        }

        public CustomObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base (collection)
        {

        }

        public CustomObservableCollection(List<T> list) :base(list)
        {

        }

        public void Repopulate(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        {
            this.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var item in collection)
                this.Items.Add(item);

            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
            this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }
    }

//TrackView simplified   

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="20">
            <Label>Artist</Label>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Artists}" DisplayMemberPath="ArtistName" SelectedValuePath="ArtistId" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArtist}">

            </ComboBox>
            <Label>Album</Label>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Albums}" DisplayMemberPath="AlbumName" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAlbum}">
            </ComboBox>
            <Label>TrackNumber</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding TrackNumber}">

            </TextBox>
            <Label>TrackName</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding TrackName}">
            </TextBox>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Uploaded}">

            </CheckBox>
            <TextBlock>
                <Hyperlink Command="{Binding AddTrackCommand}">Add Track</Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>

        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: what is the stacktrace of yhe nullreference ecxeption? where exactly it is thrown?

Comment: StackTrace "   at MML.Windows.CustomObservableCollection`1.Repopulate(IEnumerable`1 collection) in ...MML.Windows\\CustomObservableCollection.cs:line 32\r\n   at ...MML.DesktopClient.ViewModels.TrackViewModel.set_SelectedArtist(Artist value) in \ViewModels\\TrackViewModel.cs:line 81 string

Comment: It says IEnumerable 1 in collection and because the Albums collection hasn't been populated yet for that artist, it is logic it doesn't work. I want to prevent that by only populating the artist combobox when artistid exists in album. Thank you for your answer

Comment: In that case I would add to SelectedArtist setter this: `this.Albums.Repopulate(_selectedArtist.Albums ?? new List<Album>());`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
context.Artists.Where(artist => artist.Albums.Any())
```

should do the trick

Comment: `.ToList()` missed out!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where should I Implement it? Sorry, quite new to programming but very eager to learn

Comment: I guess in the GetArtistList method, but you have not shown how it looks like. Only the Where(...) part is importat - it demostrate how to query atrists that have albums